# JPA: How to improve performance in persistance of OneToMany relationships

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have two classes :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="folder")
public class Folder{
@Id
public String reference;
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
public List<Client> clients= new ArrayList<>();
public Date createDate;
}
```

and the second class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
public class Client implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int id;
    public String name;
}
```

in my database i created an intermadiate table

```
 create table folder_clients (folder_ref varchar(20) not null, clients_id int not null)
    alter table folder_clients add constraint UK_clientid unique (clients_id)
    alter table folder_clients add constraint FK_idClient foreign key (clients_id) references client
    alter table folder_clients add constraint FK_refFolder foreign key (folder_ref) references folder
```

now i have a service that persists a folder, so automatically it persists all clients related to it, and this is done throught a Folder Repository:

```
 folder.getClients().add(client);
 folderRepository.save(folder);
```

Everything is good and working, but when i execute the SQL Profiler i find that it executes many statements, which affect performance.

Is there a better way to improve my code, in order to reduce number of statements executed by hibernate and improve performance ?

thank you

Comment: wanna explain how this line works `List<Client> clients= new ArrayList<>();` if `Client` isn't an actual class?

Comment: sorry its a mistake, i edited, the second class is Client

Comment: well you have to insert/update every client which is connected to the folder. if its an insert, you won't be able to reduce the amount of statements. for update it depends on what you update and how you determine who gets updated. i think you are missing some sql understanding on what is possible and what not

Comment: You could, in principle, get rid of the intermediary table by using a `@JoinColumn` instead. This will reduce the number of writes, but may (or may not, depending on your use case) negatively affect query performance and/or updates.

Comment: Why did you create an intermediate table ? Could you add the Sql profiler log that shows generated queries? You can also set up  hibetnate log level to check the  generated queries  as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there many-to-many association or one-to-many association between client and folder in that case?

If that is one-to-many association, I suggest you use bidirectional mapping. Because you don't need the third table for this situation. So (briefly), fewer queries will be generated by hibernate and the performance will increase.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="folder")
public class Folder {
    @Id
    private String reference;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="folder", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Client> clients= new ArrayList<>();

    private Date createDate;

    //getters and setters
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
public class Client implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "folder_id")
    private Folder folder;

    //getters and setters
}
```

See this awesome post about @OneToMany relationships: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

But, if your case is many-to-many see: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: You don't need to make the relationship bidirectional to get rid of the intermediary table, see my comment above

Comment: To avoid intermediary table yes, you are right. But the bidirectional increases the performance. 
See this [link](https://vladmihalcea.com/2017/03/29/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

And this post is about performance.

Comment: you are right, my bad. For future reference, it is worth noting that this behavior of first inserting child entities and then updating the foreign key is vendor-specific: Hibernate and EclipseLink follow this approach, while DataNucleus and OpenJPA do not

Answer (score 0):

Making the one to many relationship bi-directional helps and by default it is eager fetch. In many cases you would need Eager fetch, but making type fetch eager will just execute n*m(n number of parent record one to many and M is the number of children records many to one mapped) queries.

The solution is fairly simple use JPA 2.1 where you need add entiry grapgh at JPA repository only

```
@Repository
public interface FolderRepo extends JpaRepository< Folder, Long> {

@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"clients")
List<Folder> findAll();
}
```

This will create Join between the bi-directional mapping of Folder-> Clients

> Blockquote you need to override equals method in each of these entity classes with ID else this will not work.
> You can get rid of complex multilevel  NamedEntityGraph at each entity class which is not needed if you have added.