# is this approach unidirectional or bidirectional

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

Consider following entities

**UserDetails (with Vehicles)**

```
@Entity
public class UserDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int userId;
private String userName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
private List<Vehicle> vehicleList = new ArrayList<>();

//getter setters
}
```

**Vehicle**

```
@Entity
public class Vehicle {

@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int vehicleId;
private String vehicleName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private UserDetails user;

//getter setters
}
```

1. Why we should use the above `@OneToMany` code if we can achieve the same db tables using the code below? Is the use of `@OneToMany` here just giving a solution of accessing the vehicle from user side 
   and if i have no requirement of accessing the vehicle for any user , this is correct configuration?
2. And since it gives same table configuration as bi-directional, what 
   should we say it uni-directional or bi-directional approach? I think as per code we cannot access vehicle from user side but user from vehicle side so is it a kind of uni-directional?

**UserDetails (without Vehicle)**

```
@Entity
public class UserDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int userId;
private String userName;

//getter setters
}
```

**Table UserDetails**

```
mysql> select * from userdetails;
+--------+------------+
| userId | userName   |
+--------+------------+
|        | First User |
+--------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Table Vehicle**

```
mysql> select * from vehicle;
+-----------+-------------+---------+
| vehicleId | vehicleName | user_id |
+-----------+-------------+---------+
|         2 | karizma     |         |
|         3 | scooty-pep  |         |
+-----------+-------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

Very good observations and questions.

Yes, you should question the `@OneToMany` if it is really needed. Question is how many elements will be on that list and how the elements will be used say on the UI. My rule of thumb is 10 elements.

Lets say you have a bank account and `@OneToMany` transactions. In the UI on some start page you show just the 10 latest and even in you go into History you get or want always a filtered list. You practically never want to see all transactions. But the `@OneToMany` collections does not give you any control - you can not filter, sort or paginate it. Just load all (or nothing in case of `FetchType.LAZY`).

It is much more flexible and better to remove the collection and load the entities via JPQL query:

```
@Query("SELECT v FROM Vehicle v WHERE v.userDetails = :userDetails")
List<Vehicle> getVehicles(UserDetails userDetails);
```

Such a query you can paginate, sort, and filter additionally. Also you can JOIN FETCH specific attributes when needed by business case.

So all in all the Query approach gives you much more control and performance then the collection. Drawback of the Query approach is that you have to write a bit more code and also navigating the domain model is harder.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Uni-directional is enough, even for the schema generation `h2ddl` tool. Keep in mind that you can also have a uni-directional mapping with only `@OneToMany` defined.

**2)** The biggest reason, apart from gaining access to the collection, in your case would be to be able to cascade the `UserDetails` operations onto the `Vehicle` entities, along with the removal of Vehicles when you clear them from the `vehicleList` collection.. which I guess you do not want to do logic-wise.

**3)** The only drawback with uni-directional would be the fact that you would need to write custom queries in order to get all vehicles for a user. With bidirectional you find a user and the vehicle collection is already there ready to be lazy loaded.

Personally I would keep that `OneToMany` but remove the `cascading`, `orphanRemoval` options.

Comment: Another drawback with uni-directional association is that performance might be compromised - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072550/jpa-how-to-improve-performance-in-persistance-of-onetomany-relationships/44073699

Answer (score 0):

The answer -afaik- is pretty much as you said

> Is the use of @OneToMany here just giving a solution of accessing the
>   vehicle from user side

So with this

> and if i have no requirement of accessing the
>   vehicle for any user , this is correct configuration?

it might not be the correct configuration. All I can think why not is that it affects on the performance: when populating the list of vehicles if there are many `UserDetail`s with many `Vehicle`s.

It is a possible to set the FetchType.LAZY for `List<Vehicle>` but depending how the JPA implementation does its internal optimization & caching that might not be always obeyed.